# How to make only two div clickable among multiple divs and send their content to php file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this php  file which is fetch  data from my database and place it into divs. this div created by while loop I want tow div only to be select then send the content to php file using Ajax.
The code execute with no problem but there is no result!!
Any help advance and I completely lost of mind !!!

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $so=$row[0];
    $s=$row[1];
    $m=$row[2];
    $a=$row[3];
    $b=$row[5];
    $c=$row[8];

?>
 <body>
 <div id="all"> //start all
 <div class="r"> //start r 
  <div id="e"><?php echo"{$s}"; ?></div>
  <div id="b"><?php echo"{$m}"; ?></div>
  <div id="a"><?php echo"{$a}"; ?></div>
  <div id="b"><?php echo"{$b}"; ?></div>
 </div> //end r
 </div> //end all
  <?php
  } //end while
  ?>
  <div id="show"></div>
```

> script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".r").click(function(){

          $data = $(this).text();
          alert($data); //it work well
               $.ajax({
               url: "view.php",
               type: "post",
               data: {
               you: $data
                     },
                     success:function(response){
                     $('#show').html(response);
                     }  
               });

           });
       });
```

> view.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_post['you'])){
printf("ok");   //just to check
}
?>
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it's readable. The easier someone can understand your code, the more likely you are to get quick and accurate answers.

Comment: Thanks for improving my code @OldPadwan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

1. IDs on a page should be unique

Now coming to your code, maintain a global variable to have select count and call the below function to allow selection of maximum 2 `div`s

```
var selectCount = 0;
$('.r div').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active') && selectCount < 2) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        selectCount++;
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        selectCount--;
    }
    else {
        alert("ony 2 allowed");
    }
});
```

To send the data to your call you can

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var result = [];
    $('.active').each(function(val){
        result.push(val);
    });
});
```

You may change the data format accordingly.

Comment: thanks It work Smoothly but if I want to change the selected  div I have to refresh  the page @Saksham

Comment: @tellme clicking that div again will deselect it

Comment: Ok selecting and un selecting  work well but sending by ajax what about it

Comment: where  suppose the push array send the result .sorry but i am confusing now @Saksham

Comment: push method put both selected value in one index  like this{ Array ( [0] => 23,65 )} not increment the index by one  @Saksham